# Create rolling estimation window for OLS regression

Tags: r, loops, time-series, regression

How can I create an event window of +/- 185 days based on my events (event dataframe) and use it in an OLS regression [lm(stock_return ~ market_return)]  and paste the coefficients in the "int" and "slope" columns at the corresponding event dates?

Stock Return Dataframe:

```
Name Date    market_return  stock_return  int slope
AAL  1.1.15   3%              5%
AAL  2.1.15   2%              1%
...
AAPL 1.1.15   3%              4%
AAPL 2.1.15   2%              3%
...
```

Event Dataframe:

```
Name Date    
AAL  4.4.15
AAL  15.6.15
...
AAPL 5.7.15
AAPL 5.6.15
...
```

Goal:

```
Name Date    market_return  stock_return  int slope
AAL  1.1.15   3%              5%
AAL  2.1.15   2%              1%
...
AAL  4.4.15   x%              x%          0.3  1.4
...
AAPL 1.1.15   3%              4%
AAPL 2.1.15   2%              3%
...
```

Thanks!